# git commit with emacs as editor under Windows

Tags: windows, git, emacs

Using git bash in Windows, I set my `core.editor` to the following:

```
 c:/program/emacs-24.2/bin/emacs --no-splash -geometry 110x58+200+2
```

Upon `git commit`, a new emacs frame opens as expected. The opened buffer has `$@` as a name. I cannot save the buffer and exit emacs. Git complains that the commit message was empty.

I have a workaround, which is to set my `core.editor` to:

```
c:/program/emacs-24.2/bin/emacs --no-splash -geometry 110x58+200+2 .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

This works, but with a couple of drawbacks:

- I must be in the directory that contains the .git folder. It does not work if I am in a child directory.
- the emacs frame that opens has two windows, one with `COMMIT_EDITMSG`, one with `$@`.

Is there a better way to choose emacs as commit editor (besides making it open in the terminal)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you either

- [run Emacs as a daemon](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon) - but that is, apparently, unix-only, or
- run `Emacs` as usual and start the server with `M-x server-start RET` or add `(server-start)` to `.emacs`

and use `emacsclient` instead of `emacs` as your `core.editor` if you insist on running `git` from the command line (hit <kbd>C-x #</kbd> in the client buffer when done editing to pass the control back to `git`).

However, the best way to use `Emacs` with `git` is `vc`:

In `Emacs`, type <kbd>C-x v d your/git/repo/root/dir RET</kbd> to get the list of modified files, mark those you want to commit with <kbd>m</kbd>, type <kbd>C-x v v</kbd> to commit them - a buffer for the commit message appears (initialized for you with the `ChangeLog` entry, if any), edit it, type <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have been using egg, and am currently looking at magit (for emacs integration). I will give vc a chance, but I still want to commit from bash sometimes. I have been looking at running Emacs as a daemon too, but it does not seem to play well with windows. `--daemon` is not a valid option.

Comment: @Gauthier: You can use `emacsclient` even if you start a regular emacs (non-daemon); however ISTR that I did use emacs daemon on windows; could it be that your emacs is old?

Comment: Color me dubious on starting emacs as a system daemon as sds's link describes, you can just tell any emacs to become a server; see the emacsclient manpage, but the short form is to just run `M-x server-start` from a running emacs and leave it up; when you're done editing any buffer a client popped, hit `C-x #`

Comment: 24.3.1. emacsclient requires `--server-file` or `--alternate-editor` (or corresponding environment variables). I took for granted that the server file was created by `emacs --daemon`, but maybe I am wrong?

Comment: @jthill: that was nice. I will have to read more in the man page.

Comment: @Gauthier: the only thing that `--daemon` does is start emacs without creating a frame (AKA "window" to the OS); @jthill is right that you can just do `server-start` in a regular emacs. I think the details of running emacsclient on windows should be discussed in a different question.

Comment: @sds: starting an emacs server and using emacsclient does answer my question exactly, I think it is the most relevant information so far and thus has its place here. The hint about `vc` and `magit` was good info but even so a bit off-topic (don't get me wrong, I am still grateful about it). If @jthill would like to write an answer with the content of his comment, I'd choose that as the answer (and ask if you can start a server from the command line, an equivalent to `--daemon` but in Windows).

Comment: @sds: I'd be happy to, but I think you need to edit it and put the part about daemon first. The daemon part is the answer, the part about vc is secondary. Also, your link gives no information about running emacs as a daemon *in Windows*; the information given by jthill (server-start, C-x #) is an essential part of the answer and should figure in the accepted answer.

Comment: I like the answer that's here - sds always had the right stuff, I only added one detail.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me under msysgit 1.7.11:

```
git config core.editor '/d/bin/emacs-24.3/bin/emacs.exe'
```

but when I switched to this:

```
git config core.editor '/d/bin/emacs-24.3/bin/emacs.exe --no-splash'
```

I got the same '$@' buffer as you do.

Comment: This is not a proper answer. Only if you have solved the OP's question, you are supposed to post. Else post them in the comments section

Answer (score 2):

Nothing I found online worked the way I wanted, and surprisingly I did not see this command yet..so, here is how I made emacs work in Git for windows:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Emacs\x86_64\bin\runemacs.exe' -wait"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another very nice interface to `git` within emacs is provided by [`magit`](https://github.com/magit/magit). The idea behind `magit` is to provide you with an interactive interface within emacs to easily run all the frequently used git commands, essentially eliminating the need for you to directly run `git` from the commands-line.

Although it is not standard (unlike `vc`, which was mentioned in another answer), you can install it very simply using the packaging system, for example from the [melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) or [marmalade](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/magit) repositories.